# adding and adjusting text and symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding text to `#mydiv` using the following code:

```
$('#mydiv').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3 
}).each(function(){ 
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('', 'line 1 line 2'); 
});
```

However I want the text `line 2` to be on a next line using a line break. I have added `\n` between the text `line 1` and `line 2` but this didn't work.

Also I would like to use some symbols in the text (see here) but this is not being recognized if I add it to the text as such:

```
$('#mydiv').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3 
}).each(function(){ 
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('', '&#9986 line 1 &#9986 line 2'); 
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dy1a674w/)

In plain CSS `&#9986` does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're setting the `textContent` of the node. This means any HTML or character entities are encoded. Instead, you need to set the `innerHTML` of the parent node:

```
$('#mydiv').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function () {
    this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.textContent.replace('', '&#9986 line 1 <br /> &#9986 line 2');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/puw0jwxy/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5my25x6c/2/)  In this jsfiddle I would like the text ("piece of text") to wrap straight under the text above it ("this is long") and not under the red X. Can you help, please? Been at it for a while with no good result :(